# Direct disk IO to/from buffer was allocated by mmap

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I need help regarding to direct disk IO. I open a file by file descriptor (fd) with flag O_DIRECT. In my user space application, I want to read large amount of data from the file and these data was used once only. A piece of un-cached memory buffer was allocated in my kernel module through "set_memory_uc" (using x86) and "remap_pfn_range" with vm_page_prot set noncached (pgrot_noncached). This buffer is aim to be used for DMA transfer via PCIe.

I tried

read(fd, buffer, len)

and

lseek(fd, 0x1000, SEEK_SET)

'buffer' VA is aligned to 4k boundary. So does 'len' (n*4k)

for somehow ,'lseek'seems works because after calling lseek it returns 0x1000

but 'read' return -1

Is there any restriction for direct disk read disk data to a mmap buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `O_DIRECT`, consider [`posix_fadvise()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/posix_fadvise) with the `POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE` flag to indicate "the data will be used only once."

Comment: +1 this. The use of `O_DIRECT` is almost always a mistake to begin with. There may be legitimate uses, but I truly cannot imagine a case where it would be beneficial (in reality, not in someone's imagination). The only arguable "advantage" is more data safety when writing, but that's an illusion. Besides that it's never faster but often _a lot_ slower than cached reads.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. My question to "posix_fadvise()" is the disk read performance. Isn't data flow path is different in between "O_DIRECT" and "posix_fadvise()" ? I image using "O_DIRECT" data was transfered bypassing OS buffer and cache and straight to physical memory for disk read. But "posix_fadvise()" still go through OS buffer and cache.

Comment: @SharonLee: See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6467/use-of-o-direct-on-linux - you believe that `O_DIRECT` will be faster but it probably won't be.

Comment: @John Zwinck: Thank you for the link. I think I get better idea regarding to how the O_DIRECT works when doing disk read. My ultimate goal is to ensure all the data filled in the destination memory block (physical memory block) before a DMA transfer. It seems I actually need 'fsync' or 'fdatasync' for it. Is 'posix_fadvise' with POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE really needed in my application? What will happen if I don't acknowledge cache is no longer needed? Will it affect disk read performance?

Comment: @SharonLee: `posix_fadvise()` does not impact the *correctness* of programs.  So you're welcome to try without it--it will not make your program do something different other than in terms of performance.